# Can I redirect stdin directly to file?

Tags: bash

In *bash*, can I somehow get rid of the `cat` part (and the fork it brings) in the following command line?

```sh
cat >some_file
```

Answer (score 5):

Use process-substitution in `bash`, to avoid `useless-use-of-cat`

```
> file
while IFS= read -r line
do
  printf "%s\n" "$line" 
done < /dev/stdin >> file
```

To read form `stdin` and append to the `file` on the run, `> file` truncates the contents of the file before reading starts.

Including this suggestion from [Leon's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6394138/leon) for a one-line option to do this,

```
while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line"; done > file
```

Comment: The same can be written as a one-liner as follows: `while read -r line; do echo "$line"; done > file`

Comment: Note that this solution is different from `cat`  in one subtle way - if the input doesn't end with a newline character, then the last line is dropped

Comment: Add an `IFS=` to the `read` to avoid stripping leading and trailing whitespace from `$line`.

Comment: Use `while IFS= read -r line || [[ $line ]]` to prevent the last line from being dropped if not terminated by a newline.

Answer (score 2):

To use only bash tools, you may do:

```
printf '%s'  "$(< infile)"
```

But both:

- I don't believe that to be much faster for small files.
- It will collect the whole file in memory, which is quite bad for long files.

That is why cat exists as a tool.